# For which primes $p$ are there integers $a,b,q$ so that $pq^2=a^4+4b^4$?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

There is a right triangle with rational sides and are $p$ iff there exists a solution.

$$pq^2=a^4+4b^4=(a^2+2b^2+2ab)(a^2+2b^2-2ab)$$
Without loss of generality, choose $a$ odd and $a,b$ coprime, then $a^2+2b^2+2ab$ and $a^2+2b^2-2ab$ are also coprime and $p\equiv 1 \pmod 4$. Divide into two cases:

1. $a^2+2b^2+2ab=pk_1^2$, $a^2+2b^2-2ab=k_2^2$
2. $a^2+2b^2+2ab=k_1^2$, $a^2+2b^2-2ab=pk_2^2$

These are the same under the transformation $a\to-a$, so I can ignore the second. Changing $a\mapsto a+b$ the system becomes:

$$a^2+b^2=pk_1^2$$
$$(a-2b)^2+b^2=k_2^2$$

There is no solution for $p=17$, and none for $p=29,61,73,89$ with $a,b<10^5$.

Comment: I'd try to use that $a^2+2ab+2b^2=(a+b)^2+b^2$ and $a^2-2ab+2b^2=(a-b)^2+b^2$.

Comment: Assume that $p\neq 2.$ Then use that $p$ divides the LHS, so it also divides the RHS. Therefore it divides, as it is prime, one term in the brackets. Assume again that $p$ divides $a$ (or $b$). What can you conclude? And always keep in mind that $p$ is prime.

Comment: @Thomas, can you please offer a more detailed hint? Thanks

Comment: Unless I've misunderstood, $(a,b,p,q)=(7,5,29,13)$ and $(a,b,p,q)=(41,39,61,445)$. May I ask for which $p$ you have solutions, and for which are you still looking?

Comment: @OldPeter I think there's something wrong with her analysis. The title clearly states that $a^4+4b^4 = pq^2$ and a quick search with even $(a,b)<10$ yields your $$7^4+4\times5^4 = 29\times13^2$$ Too bad she's no longer active in MSE.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I am getting really stupid in my old age, a rational triangle with area $p$ means that $p$ will be a Congruent Number. The first prime examples are $p=5$ and $p=7$. But a solution of $pq^2=a^4+4b^4$ must have $p \equiv 1 (\bmod 4)$, as the OP states. Thus the "iff" statement in the first sentence must be wrong.

Comment: Old Peter quickly found the solution, $$7^4+4\times5^4 = 29\times13^2$$ so there was something wrong with her analysis.